# How does a Raman Laser work?

Tags: laser, raman-spectroscopy

I am trying to find out how a Raman Laser itself works. By that I mean how does it use stimulated Raman scattering to produce gain and thus make a laser. I have some knowledge of how lasers work but for this all I want is a base level description of how a Raman laser goes about making the laser particularly how its gain works.

I have looked at a bunch of online resources but they are all over. Namely because Raman Spectroscopy seems to be huge and covers a ton of stuff. No one website seems to talk specifically about a actual Raman Laser that uses Stimulated Raman Scattering for its gain.

Comment: [Raman Lasers](https://www.rp-photonics.com/raman_lasers.html)